# how to fix this unterminated string literal error?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

It is giving me an unterminated string literal error: `var image_file_name = "<br/>` for this line below:

```
var image_file_name = "<?php echo str_replace("\n", "", $image_file_name); ?>";
```

Any ideas on how this can fixed? Open to all ideas to test :)

Comment: This is valid PHP code.  The unterminated string literal is coming from something else.

Comment: @user1384419 To elaborate since i can't edit the original comment, the unterminated string literal could be that you forgot to close a quote before the block of PHP code so the error shows on that line but in fact, the string could start many lines before where the error is showing.  You can post more code, or see where you may have forgotten to close a `'` or `"` above that line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're removing `\n` newlines but not `\r` carriage returns. Try removing both. It looks like IE (and possibly other browsers) also treats `\r` as a line break.

Perhaps:

```
str_replace(array("\n","\r"), "", $image_file_name)
```

*(I'm assuming that `$image_file_name` contains Windows-style `\r\n` line breaks, not *nix-style `\n` line breaks.)*

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var image_file_name = '<?php echo str_replace("\n", "", $image_file_name); ?>';
```

Trying to avoid the temptation to ask why you're assigning a php snippet to a JavaScript variable... :p

Comment: PHP will be executed before the JavaScript is sent to the browser and parsed, so JS quote choice won't make a difference.

Comment: Ahh, guess I was just assuming the execution context was a JavaScript engine, but that doesn't make sense given the original error that was thrown...

Answer (score 1):

Please use it will solve the issues

```
 addcslashes($string, "\x00..\x1f\x22\x27\x5c")
```

Answer (score 0):

What i usually do.

Create an input type hidden, fill his value with the php value and select it using a selector $("#hiddenData").val();

So you don't need to write the data in your script block using PHP.
If you use a mvc framework it's a lot cleaner.